# Publish artifact in maven repository from nexus

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, nexus, sonatype

I "uploaded" my repository to oss.sonatype.org with the wrong version so I removed the repository from: "Staging Repositories" section.

Now uploaded agian with the right version but I did "Staging Repositories".

When I'm searching it in "Artifact Search" or "Welcome" tab, I see my artifact but I don't understand how to move on? There are no buttons to click on.

[image]

Comment: When you say "how to move on" and "..click on..", what is it you want to achieve? Use your project as a maven dependency?

Comment: @mattias Yes. I want to publish my project as a maven dependency.

Comment: It is published, you use it by declaring the following in your pom file, `<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.universityfinalprojects</groupId>
  <artifactId>tparser</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>`.

Comment: This wasn't the version I wanted to publish. How do I publish 1.2.6 from the picture I provided?

Comment: You mean a fixed/"released" version instead of the snapshot artifact you uploaded?

Comment: No. I mean I want to publish one of the other versions I uploaded: 1.2.6-snapshot or 0.2.5-snapshot.

Comment: You simply can't publish/release it from nexus. You need to create a release from it first and stage that release afterwards you can release it...At the moment you have a SNAPSHOT which can't be released via Nexus you need to do that via Maven on command line...(maven-release-plugin..)